# Angular 5 Dropdown value not show as selected on start

Tags: angular

I am facing a Problem with Angular 5 Forms, when I Get Exchanges Array of Object from Server, after Iteration I tried to populate in HTML but default value not show while other fields are populated from other service

**This is My HTML**

```
<select formControlName="Exchange">
<option [value]="ExchangeName.Exchange" *ngFor='let ExchangeName of ExchangeNameAndPairsForDropDown'>{{ExchangeName.Exchange}}</option>
</select>
```

**This is My TS Code**

```
if (sourceExchangeArray && sourceExchangeArray.length) {
              for (var e = 0; e < sourceExchangeArray.length; e++) {
                this.sourceExchangeEmptyBox = (<FormArray>this.sourceTargetForm.get('sourceExchange')).push(
                  new FormGroup({
                    'Exchange' : new FormControl(sourceExchangeArray[e].Exchange , Validators.required),
                    'APIKey' : new FormControl(sourceExchangeArray[e].APIKey , Validators.required),
                    'NameInstance': new FormControl(sourceExchangeArray[e].NameInstance , Validators.required),
                    'Secret' : new FormControl(sourceExchangeArray[e].Secret , Validators.required),
                    '_id' : new FormControl(sourceExchangeArray[e]._id , Validators.required)
                  })
                );
              }
            }


getExchangeNameAndPairs () {
    this.ApplicationServices.getExchangeNameAndPairs('/api/exchanges/getExchangeNameAndPairs').then((success:any) => {
      if (success.ExchangeNameAndPairs && success.ExchangeNameAndPairs.length) {
        this.ExchangeNameAndPairsForDropDown = success.ExchangeNameAndPairs;
      }
      },
      error => {
        console.log('error', error);
      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value option is wrong: [value]
it should be: (value)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select formControlName="Exchange">
<option *ngFor='let ExchangeName of ExchangeNameAndPairsForDropDown' [ngValue]="ExchangeName.Exchange">{{ExchangeName.Exchange}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The code in your question uses `value`. I have used `ngValue`?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who's facing this, you should use [ngValue] instead of [value].